# Change Google Places picker Action bar color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, google-maps-api-2, android-styles, android-compatibility

Good morning, i am quite new in Android and i have a problem setting the color of the built-in action bar in Google Places Picker. The documentation of this one clearly says that the action bar color inherits the matherial theme style of the project. The problem is that i have `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and the color of this style isn't passed to the Google Place Picker because it uses only the colors of material themes. 
I would like to ask if it's somehow possible to replace `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` with any material theme so i can use that to set the action bar color in  place picker.
I have tried in this way:
styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>


        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

v21\styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

My activity extends AppCompatActivity so when i change to Material theme android throws in exception because an AppCompatStyle is needed.
Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this problem:
The appcompat in version > 21 extends material theme and so also this kind of style allows to modify the place picker color. To change color, you have to insert in @color the values for "primary" and "primaryDark"; this is a bug of google that isnn't still fixed.