# PlacePicker widget does not use theme color

Tags: android, google-maps, colors, themes, google-places-api

I referred to this question: [Change Google Places picker Action bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523366/change-google-places-picker-action-bar-color). But the solution suggested there does not seem to solve my problem and I'm starting to think that I might be doing something else wrong.

I am compiling `appcompat-v7:23.0.+` and my current theme in styles.xml is

```
<style name = "AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

I remembered to change the theme in the manifest file to use `AppTheme` as well.

My layout looks like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background = "@color/backgroundGrey"
android:theme = "@style/AppTheme"
tools:context=".PlacePickerActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

I have no idea why the placepicker isn't picking up the same colors. Does anyone have any ideas? Any criticism is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try to add this properties : <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item> 
</style> in your current theme.

Comment: See here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733340/placepicker-doesnt-pick-up-material-theme

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked at that link and I still can't seem to get it to work. Would it be because I am using an AppCompat theme instead of a Material theme?

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in Android.  It works fine for me on Android 6.0.1, but it doesn't work on KitKat.  Hopefully they will fix it soon: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7968&q=PlacePicker&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Comment: Strange, I am using lollipop so I assume it should work since many places state that it is only an issue from API < 21. May I ask if you are using Theme.AppCompat for your theme or Theme.Material?

Comment: Using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`  Was able to change the background colors on Android 6.0.1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EL9oq.jpg

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using the latest version of the Google Play Services client library?  The bug mentioned earlier should be fixed in the latest version (I'll make a note to close it out). Also can you try setting android:colorPrimary and android:colorPrimaryDark?